# how do I redirect a user to a certain page using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following rule defined in the .htaccess file of my webapplication's root directory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/classes/captcha.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?client=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

this rule give the facility of typing the url like this `xyz.com/abc/page1` which is in original is equal to `xyz.com/index.php?client=abc&page=page1`

Now what I want is that when a user types in `http://xyz.com/abc/page1`, the address bar of the browser should display the original url i.e. `'http://xyz.com/index.php?client=abc&page=page1'`
currently if I type "`http://xyz.com/abc/page1`" the address bar url doesn't change.

Please help me modify this rule.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the redirect flag:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?client=$1&page=$2 [R=301, L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help jasonbar :)
I had to modify your answers a little bit for it to work correctly. like this.
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?client=$1&page=$2 [L,R=301]